# Missing clipboard formats WinApi

Tags: windows, winapi

My problem is about WinApi clipboard formats. The scenario is:

1. Service application enumerates processes and looks for my application. If it's not found it will spawn process with winlogon.exe duplicated token from user session to act as system.
2. Each time clipboard has been updated application is enumerating formats. It works for CF_TEXT, CF_UNICODE, etc... But I need CF_HDROP - it's missing. It always have 49161 IDataObject with no formats inside.
3. If I try to run application manually from user context it detects CF_HDROP.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You went wrong when you decided to describe your program instead of taking the time to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user token **integrity level** is an answer.
This is why some clipboard formats were missing.